# Continuity and U-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

Problem:

> If $f$ is continuous and $\int_0^4f(x)\,\mathrm dx=10$, find $\int_0^2f(2x)\,\mathrm dx.$

Getting the answer is very simple but what I have trouble understanding is the condition of $f$ being continuous. Integrals only require that the function be bounded over the interval defined by the bounds of integration. Integrals do not require continuity. I did not use the fundamental theorem of calculus to solve the problem, a theorem which requires continuity for both parts of it. So, why must $f$ be continous?

Comment: The Riemann integral needs more than boundedness: $\chi_{\Bbb Q}$ doesn't have an integral, e.g. Or are you doing Lebesgue integration? Then you need measurability.

Comment: See the proposition and the hypotheses of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)

Comment: to find the value of an integral, you need the function to be continous and bounded only over the region of which you are integrating. In this case, if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,4]$ then $f(2x)$ must be on $[0,2]$